# Concatenate a list of lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

At first I have 2 lists, l1 and l2

```
l1 = [['a','1','b','c','now'],['d','2','e','f','tomorrow']] 

l2 = [['11:30', '12:00'],['13:00', '13:30']]
```

What I want is to create a new list of list with the first two elements of each list from the l1, getting: `newList = [['a', '1'], ['d', '2']]`

Then, from each list in newList I want to add a list from l2, to get:

```
newList = [['a', '1', '11:30', '12:00'], ['d', '2', '13:00', '13:30']]
```

At last I want to add the last element from each list in l1:

```
newList = [['a', '1', '11:30', '12:00','now'], ['d', '2', '13:00', '13:30','tomorrow']]
```

What I have until now is this:

```
newList =[]

for i in l1:
   names = i[:2]
   newList.append(names)
```

But now I don't know how I do extend to get the other elements..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With list comprehension:

```
newList = [x[: 2] + y + x[-1:] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
```

Comment: @Pynchia `x[-1]` would return an element, not a list, so you would have to put `[ x [ -1 ] ]`. I don't know if the latter is faster than `x[-1:]`.

Comment: true, sorry let's scratch that, I was half-sleeping

Answer (score 3):

Use `zip` along with list comprehension.

```
>>> l1 = [['a','1','b','c','now'],['d','2','e','f','tomorrow']]
>>> l2 = [['11:30', '12:00'],['13:00', '13:30']]
>>> [[x[0], x[1]] + y + [x[-1]] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
[['a', '1', '11:30', '12:00', 'now'], ['d', '2', '13:00', '13:30', 'tomorrow']]
>>> [x[:2] + y + [x[-1]] for x, y in zip(l1, l2)]
[['a', '1', '11:30', '12:00', 'now'], ['d', '2', '13:00', '13:30', 'tomorrow']]
```

Comment: can't you explain me using append and extend ? i am new in this, and i want to start from the basic..